# making the listcolumns search dynamic

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am following upn on a tute on datatables and found a code which basically iterates over the columns for a order clause but in the case, i do not have a list of order columns hardcoded, its a dynamic list

how can I change this

```
<cfif form["order[0][column]"] gt 0>
    ORDER BY 
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '1'>
    empname <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '2'>
    empno <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '3'>
    ic <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>   
</cfif>
```

to be dynamic as my list variable is a comma separated as `id,name,email` and lots more

Comment: Please edit your question and show the relavent parts of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The direction I always would go will be to create a Coldfusion array or structure with this fieldNames, like the following.

```
<cfset orderColumnReference = ['empname', 'empno', 'ic', 'id', 'name', 'email', ...]>
<cfif form["order[0][column]"] GTE ArrayLen(orderColumnReference)>
  <cfset orderByColumn = orderColumnReference[form["order[0][column]"]]>
    ORDER BY 
    #orderByColumn# <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: I am concerned that this may open the query to injection attacks.

Comment: I don't share that concern.  I am however, puzzled by the use of a structure or array rather than a list.

Comment: I have always felt like arrays are more readable than lists. So I prefer using them. @james this will only work for a predefined set of column names, so SQL injection is not a possibility.